# How can I fix this regex? (nmap results)

Tags: python, regex, capture-group

I am attempting to parse text in to 4 capture groups, but I am running in to an issue.

My regex is:

```
(\d{1,5})\/(tcp|udp)\s+open\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)?
```

Some sample input is:

```
Nmap scan report for X
Host is up (0.097s latency).
Not shown: 192 closed ports
PORT     STATE         SERVICE       VERSION
135/udp  open          msrpc
137/udp  open          netbios-ns    Microsoft Windows XP netbios-ssn (workgroup: THINC)
135/tcp open  msrpc        Microsoft Windows RPC
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn  Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds Windows XP microsoft-ds
```

This works almost perfectly.  The problem is on the line for 135/udp, there is no version field, so my capture group 4 for that line is wrapping around and grabbing the entire next line (starting with 137/udp).

What I would like is for the capture group 4 to be empty / null for the line for 135/udp (or anywhere where the version field is blank).

It seems like my last `.*` should not go past a line terminator, but it is.  I have also included the `?` after my last capture group to try to make that optional, as in to allow the null value.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?  It would be more helpful to explain my mistake versus just providing me a working regex.

[Visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU4HF.png)

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Python's re library.  However, the issue also applies to the parser on regex101.com, so I assume it is my expression more than an implementation flaw.

Comment: @BenF: It's not about "implementation flaw", it's that different engines implement regex differently. For example, JavaScript has no lookbehinds, non-magic Vim needs to escape `+` but not `*`, Ruby has recursive patterns, Perl has bunch of black magic... and it's even in the [tag:regex] tag: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` appears to be matching newlines. This is unexpected for me - I would have expected `\s` to match whitespace only.

Try matching tabs and spaces only instead:
`[ \t]` instead of `\s`.

and being a bit more demanding - meaning setting the spaces and non-spaces that are expected with `+`, not with `*`:

`(\d{1,5})\/(tcp|udp)[ \t]+open[ \t]+(\S+)[ \t]+(.*)`

The `(\S+)` is the one entry expected after open and spaces.
But since we are only interested in those lines that continue after that:
`[ \t]+` demands there to be space after that entry (excluding the line that ends there ) - with `(.*)` capturing all that comes after the space.

Comment: Thanks! `(\d{1,5})\/(tcp|udp)\s+open\s+(\S+)[ \t]*(.*)?` works as does `(\d{1,5})\/(tcp|udp)[ \t]+open[ \t]+(\S+)[ \t]*(.*)?`

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't yet have enough reputation for it to show.

Comment: I thought you wanted to exclude the line that ends after 'msrpc'. To do that, you would need the version with `(\S+)[ \t]+(.*)` at the end.

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped :)

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer, though, I believe. You may have to wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by bytepusher, I had a \s that was matching newlines.  I replaced the \s with an explicit match for spaces or tabs [ \t], as in:

```
(\d{1,5})\/(tcp|udp)\s+open\s+(\S+)[ \t]*(.*)?
```

Most correctly, I replaced all instances of /s with explicit matches for the expected spacing characters:

```
(\d{1,5})\/(tcp|udp)[ \t]+open[ \t]+(\S+)[ \t]*(.*)?
```

Comment: I think you can further simply the regex as, iirc, most unix/linux commands separate fields by `\t`

Comment: I'm pretty sure escaping the slash in the PORT column value is not necessary in Python.  The `?` at the end of your pattern is not necessary either because the last capture group accepts zero or more characters.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOSDEr/1)  Otherwise, you have this pattern as tight/efficient as it will go without potentially compromising accuracy.